# returning number of empty cells from spread sheet using qlikview expre

Tags: qlikview

I need  an expression that make a textbox object to return number of empty cells from spread sheet in qlikview and i also want to see the list of those cells in a table box, this is what i did but it is returning wrong answers

`=Count(IsNull([Candidate FullName]))` for the expresion

and for the script this is what i did

```
Load 
  Distinct 
  if( IsNull([Candidate Name]),'[Candidate Name]','[Candidate Name]') as Not_Submitted,
  Spec,
  [Candidate Name]
  //[Closing date] as [Spec_Due_Date] 
  //if((Closing date])!=([CV Send Date]))
Resident 
  ZAK_RECRUTMENT 
Where 
  IsNull([Candidate Name])
//[Closing date] <=Today() and [Candidate Name] = Null()
;
```

Answer (score 0):

So to count the nulls you'll need to use either:

`nullcount([Candidate Name])`

or

`count(if(isnull([Candidate Name]),1)`

The standard count function doesn't count nulls so it needs an if.

For the script part this makes no sense to me:

`if( IsNull([Candidate Name]),'[Candidate Name]','[Candidate Name]') as Not_Submitted,`

AS this is going to return the words [Candidate Name] no matter if it is a null or not.

```
if( IsNull([Candidate Name]),'[Candidate Name]',[Candidate Name]) as Not_Submitted,
```

This will return the list of non-null Candidates and the words [Candidate Name] for those that are null.

I am assuming the Spec field is the identifier so if you select [Candidate Name] you'll get the list of Specs without Names